# 'DBOfflineOrder' does not have a primary key and can not be updated swift realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have entity in Realm:

```
class DBOfflineOrder: Object {
    dynamic var date: String = "" //
    dynamic var orderDescription: String = ""
    dynamic var email: String = ""
    dynamic var phone: String = "" 
    dynamic var login: String = "" 
    dynamic var number: String = "" 
    dynamic var amount: Double = 0.0 
    dynamic var discount: Double = 0.0 

    let products = List<ProductOffline>()
}
```

As you notice, it does not have a primary key, because it don't have an id.

When i call following:

```
let realm = Repository.initRealm()
realm.beginWrite()
let offlineOrder = DBOfflineOrder(order: _order)
realm.add(offlineOrder, update: true)
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

I got an crash. It says:

> 'DBOfflineOrder' does not have a primary key and can not be updated

But i don't need a pk and don't have property that may act like that.

Comment: do you want to update the object?

Comment: @hardikparmar i  need to create it and set properties, and not update after.

Comment: then do `realm.add(offlineOrder)` only

Comment: if you need to update realm object, it has to has primary key.
however, if you do not want to use primary key, then you could use `KVO`

Answer (score 0):

To update realm object it is necessary to have primary key. So if you do not want to update the object then you can just use `realm.add(offlineOrder)`.